# Is it possible to send data to a server and not download a response?

Tags: java, php, android

I would like to use an android app to send GPS coordinates using a prepaid sim card. My theory is that if i don't download any response and i only send requests, i won't drain the card of money.

To test this: Is there a way to 1. On android; create a certain type of request that does not expect a return? 2. on the server side; (preferably php -lamp stack) not deliver a response?

I feel like it would be something to do with UDP versus TCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a socket connection to your server and writing using UDP protocol will do the trick as **Steve explain above**
Here what i did similiar without responce

```
InetAddress serverAddr = Inet4Address.getByName("addressIP");
Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
socket.getOutputStream().write("your data".getBytes());
```

Where SERVERPORT stands for 8080,4040 anything depends on your server. I Used this piece of code to communicate with Server

Comment: This is run from Android? And it does not expect a response right? Hit it and quit it?

Comment: @MarshallHouse All this says is how to write to a socket.  By your question, I assumed that you were doing this over a RESTful application.  This just tells you how to send data to a socket if you have your server implemented such that this is an acceptable practice.

Comment: @SteveP. If i knew how to phrase the question better i would have, but i wouldn't have known to write to a socket so this is more useful to me. I'm more of a web guy and i don't get into "sockets" and things of that nature. I marked your answer +1 because it was helpful and affirming of my assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP typically runs over TCP.  If you wrote a client server model that uses UDP or some sort of hybrid approach instead, then this could work.  While I am by no means an expert, I don't know of any commonly used RESTful applications that run over UDP.

Comment: If i wrote a client server that used UDP, what programming language might that involve? C++?

Comment: @MarshallHouse UDP is just a protocol, so whatever language suited you best.

Comment: @Sameer please elaborate in a new answer if you have a good idea of more precisely how to do it. thanks!